# Trying to store submenu items to render out after main menu

Tags: php, menus, walker

I'm using a custom nav walker to render out the main menu, during this I want to store the second level navigation items to use/ render out later in a separate area of the page.

I want these second level navigation items to display block, if you're currently in that section (i.e. if you're on 'services' or a subpage of 'services' then the submenu will display block). Also, if I hover over "services" I want the submenu to show.

Currently I've done the submenu in a separate custom nav walker - but the navigation only displays when you're in the section, not when you hover over the main menu item. Also, with how I currently have it setup it shows the menu background/ styles on pages that don't have submenus

This is my existing nav walker for the submenu only:

```
class MainSubmenuCustomWalker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array())
    {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            return;
        }
        parent::start_lvl($output, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array())
    {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            return;
        }
        parent::end_lvl($output, $depth,$args);
    }

    // Don't print top-level elements
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id=0)
    {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            return;
        }
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array())
    {
        if ($depth == 0) {
            return;
        }
        parent::end_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output)
    {
        $current_element_markers = array( 'current-menu-item', 'current-menu-parent', 'current-menu-ancestor' );
        $current_class = array_intersect( $current_element_markers, $element->classes );
        $ancestor_of_current = !empty($current_class);

        if (0 == $depth && !$ancestor_of_current) {
            return;
        }

        $id = $element->ID;
        if (($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1) && isset($children_elements[$id])) {
            foreach ($children_elements[$id] as $child) {
                if (!isset($newlevel)) {
                    $newlevel = true;
                    //start the child delimiter
                    $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
                }
                parent::display_element($child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output);
            }
            unset($children_elements[$id]);
        }

        if (isset($newlevel) && $newlevel) {
            //end the child delimiter
            $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }
    }
}
```

It is being called from here, which renders the menu container even if there are no submenu items :(

```
<div class="main-submenu-navbar navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button"
        class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#main-submenu-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<?php Menu::submenus(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the same kind of problem and I decided to ditch the `walker` alltogether and use the `wp_get_nav_menu_object` and `wp_get_nav_menu_items` functions instead.

If you `var_dump($menu_items)` you can see which properties are available.

Here's a snippet of my code that builds the menu named 'main' for my twitter bootstrap menu:

```
    $menu_name = 'main'; // name of your menu
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_name);

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);



    $tmpWPMenu = ""; // string variable where the menu is stored

    // collect the menu-items (if any) and store them temporarily in 
    // the $tmpChildren array with the $key = id of parent

    $tmpChildren = array();
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        if (intval($menu_item->menu_item_parent) > 0) {
            $tmpChildren[$menu_item->menu_item_parent][] = $menu_item;
        }
    }

   // Now loop again and build it, 
   // when a matching ID is encountered in the $tmpChildren array, build the submenu:
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;

        if (intval($menu_item->menu_item_parent) == 0) {


            // Does $tmpChildren contain a $key that is the id of this menu-item?
            if (array_key_exists($menu_item->ID, $tmpChildren)) {

                $tmpWPMenu .= '<li class="dropdown">';
                $tmpWPMenu .= ' <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i> '.$title.' <b class="caret"></b></a>';


                $tmpWPMenu .= ' <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                foreach ($tmpChildren[$menu_item->ID] as $subMenuItem) {
                    $tmpWPMenu .= '<li><a href="/ik/"><!--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>--> ' . $subMenuItem->title . '</a></li>';
                }
                $tmpWPMenu .= ' </ul>';
                $tmpWPMenu .= '</li>';

            } else {

                $tmpWPMenu .= '<li>';
                $tmpWPMenu .= '<a href="#"></i> '.$title.' </a>';
                $tmpWPMenu .= '</li>';

            }

        }



    }

    // Do something with the $tmpWPMenu, in my case I pass it 
    // to the Smarty template engine that I use
    $tmpNavBarFindAndReplace['wp_menu'] = $tmpWPMenu;


    print $gBSOManager->pPageO->mRender($tmpNavBarFindAndReplace, 'mijn/navbar.html',true);
```

I hope this might help (or provide insight) :)
Cheers,
T